# Collada morph animation blend shape Maya

Tags: swift, scenekit, maya

we created a simple animation in Maya using keyed blend shapes. Exported it as a .dae.

I've been trying and researching everywhere and it seems like SceneKit will not play this type of animation.

I can see my Morphers in Xcode as well as the animation key, but nothing ever happens when playing this animation.

I've seen a couple threads about that on Autodesk and here, and it looks like no one have solved this issue. So my question is the following: is there anyone out there that was able to play an animation from a .dae file using blend shapes?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

No, I don't believe this is possible.  I went down this same path about a year ago.  In the end I used one of my developer code-level tech support tickets AND filed a bug report.  I got action on both fronts.  Apple said that it SHOULD work.  However, it successfully played any kind of transform animations (position, scale, rotation), but wouldn't play any keyed blend shape ones.

Then I had them look at my DAE file from Maya.  They said that the exported file was not a valid Collada.  They pointed me specifically to what was wrong with the way Maya exported it, and even told me what would need to be changed in order to make it work.

I went to the Collada DAE file format spec and confirmed the Apple engineer was correct about what was wrong with the exported file.  I opened a case with AutoDesk.  After a few initial questions, I never heard back.

Upon making the change Apple mentioned, it still wouldn't work.  **But get this** -- after making their changes, the Preview app on the Mac would play the animation correctly!  But never in Xcode.

Here is an Apple Dev Forum link to my posting there: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/308819#308819

Here's the same project I was using: https://bitbucket.org/drewster77/scenekitimportedanimtest

If you get it working, please post the solution here!

Comment: Hi Drewster, you are the person I was talking about that wrote those threads! 
So yes that's pretty much a dead end at this point, and I can't believe you got it to show up in Preview it's crazy (do you still have the file that works in Preview?)

I even tried programmatically and it does not work. 

If I ever find anything, I will answer my own question and let you know.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: I think I do have that file, yes.  Or if not, I have the original file and the instructions they gave on what was needed to change.  It might actually be in that GitHub project -- I haven't looked.

Comment: @drewster thanks for the response. I haven't been able to successfully export a model with blendshapes on Maya 2020. The geometry is messed up. What was your workaround?